# Windows 7 keyboard input hangs while reading from usb hard drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, io

There is a strange behavior of windows 7. I like to listen to music while coding (surprising), so I always carry with me my usb storage and play music from it. Sometimes while playing a song it kind of "hangs" (guess loads the buffer). What is strange that my mouse keeps working, but any input that I type is not appearing until it "releases". Why does it happens? Why it doesn't receive IO from keyboard but does receive mouse? Why does the system hang at all, shouldn't interrupts handle this?